# now() default values are all showing same timestamp

Tags: postgresql, transactions, timestamp, postgresql-9.1

I have created my tables with a column (type: timestamp with timezone) and set its default value to `now()` (`current_timestamp()`).

I run a series of inserts in separate statements in a single function and I noticed all the timestamps are equal down to the (ms), is the function value somehow cached and shared for the entire function call or transaction?

Comment: `no()`? You mean `now()`? And `current_timestamp` has no trailing parenthesis for historical reasons.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

That is [expected and documented](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-CURRENT) behaviour:

From the manual:

> *Since these functions return the start time of the current transaction, their values do not change during the transaction. This is considered a feature: the intent is to allow a single transaction to have a consistent notion of the "current" time, so that multiple modifications within the same transaction bear the same time stamp.*

If you want something that changes each time you run a statement, you need to use `statement_timestamp()` or even `clock_timestamp()` (again see the description in the manual)

Answer (score 15):

`now()` and `current_timestamp` (the latter without parentheses - odd SQL standard) are [`STABLE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/xfunc-volatility.html) functions returning the point in time when the *transaction started* as `timestamptz`.

Consider one of the [other options PostgreSQL offers](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-CURRENT), in particular **`statement_timestamp()`**. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-CURRENT)

> `statement_timestamp()` returns the start time of the current statement (more specifically, the time of receipt of the latest command message from the client)

Related:

- [Difference between now() and current_timestamp](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/63549/3684)

Comment: Seems to me now the `current_timestamp` returns the current timestamp, and not when the transaction started. I tried it in pg admin with simple `select current_timestamp` statement. `select now()` still returns the timestamp when the transaction started.

Comment: @Eqzt111: Most clients (incl. pgAdmin and psql) run with "autocommit" on by default, i.e. every (block of) executed command(s) is wrapped into a transaction and committed automatically. Executing `SELECT now()` will report (almost) the same time as `SELECT statement_timestamp()` or `SELECT clock_timestamp()` this way. See: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/63549/3684

Comment: Autocommit is set to false in my pg admin settings, that's why `select to_char(now(), 'YYYY.MM.DD HH24:MI:SS')` returns the same value until I use `commit`, but `select to_char(current_timestamp, 'YYYY.MM.DD HH24:MI:SS')` always returns the current time on the server. Give it a try.

Comment: @Eqzt111: I gave it a try, and there is no difference whatsoever, as expected. Would be a *very* odd bug if there was any difference. If you can reproduce your observation, please report a bug, including your environment (pg version, client, ...)