# PgPreparedStatement and caching

Tags: sql, postgresql, jdbc

I would like to read the current timestamp from the PostgreSQL database with the following query:

```
select now();
```

I use the following PG driver: `postgresql-9.4.1212`

I execute the statment as prepared statement.

Multiple calls of the above mentioned prepared statements always return the same value, so the query seems to be cached somewhere/somehow.

How could I accomplish that the query gets executed physically on the database every time?

Comment: Unrelated, but: `postgresql-9.4.1212` is a really, really old release. You should use a more up-to-date version of the driver

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should consider using other functions, like `statement_timestamp()`.
Please consider reading this question, that is somehow related to yours:
[now() default values are all showing same timestamp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12216802/now-default-values-are-all-showing-same-timestamp).